# How to check if a List A is a sub-list in List B using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

Do I have to write my own Function ?

Is there a built in Function in List to checks another list for membership ?

Comment: I want my code to be optimized, so I am looking for some in-built function.

Comment: There is no particular reason to assume that built-in functions are more "optimized" than functions you write yourself. I don't know what you mean by "sub-list", though. If you're asking if a single list item appears in both List A and List B then you'll have to do the obvious comparisons yourself. The [`List.Contains` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim ListA As New List(Of Int32)(New Int32() {1, 3, 5})
Dim ListB As New List(Of Int32)(New Int32() {1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 7})
Dim isSubList = Not ListA.Except(ListB).Any() 'True'
```

[MSDN: Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

Comment: Nice!  Which version of .Net did this appear in?